# What's the meaning of a lack in $V$ if the resistance is zero?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, potential, electrical-resistance, voltage

We know that $V=RI$. If $R=0$ then $V=0$ regardless of the amount of $I$. There is the conduct, because we have displacement of $q$ in the formula $q=It$. But what's the meaning of a lack of $V$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, keep in mind that Ohm's law applies in the situation of a steady current. Second, $V$ in Ohm's law should perhaps be $\Delta V$; it is the *difference* in electric potential between two points in a circuit.

The straightforward interpretation of $V=IR$ in the limit $R\rightarrow 0$ is that the potential difference between two points in a circuit with zero resistance between them approaches zero. For example, imagine a circuit consisting of a battery connected to a light bulb with copper wire. To a first approximation, all of the resistance in the circuit is contained in the light bulb. The resistance of the copper wire is approximately zero in comparison. As a result, if you follow the copper wire from one terminal of the battery to the part of the lightbulb it is connected to, the electric potential almost does not change along this path, even though current flows through the copper wire.

The interpretation of the $R\rightarrow 0$ limit is more subtle if $V$ does not go to zero. This happens in a short circuit. If the *total resistance* of the circuit goes to zero, and a finite voltage is applied through a battery, then the current must go to infinity in order for $V=IR$ to remain true. The correct physical interpretation here is that Ohm's law breaks down, since this is not a steady state situation.